# image cropped in croppie is not correct

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using croppie plug-in to crop my image.But when I crop the image,the resulted image is not as like i cropped.[image: The Image I used to crop]

[image: The Resulted Image]

Comment: var $cropdiv = $('#MyProfUpload'); 
        $cropdiv.croppie({
            viewport: {
                width: 175,
                height: 175,
                type: 'circle'
            },
            boundary: {
                width: 200,
                height: 200
            },
        });

Comment: if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $cropdiv.croppie('bind', {
                        url: e.target.result
                    });
                }   
            }

Comment: $cropdiv.croppie('result', {
                  type: 'canvas',
                  size: 'viewport'
              }).then(function (resp) { console.log(resp);});

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found out that it was because the image had the style (in a css file)
max-width:100%
I removed it, and croppie began to work as expected.
I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I know its been a while since this question was made. But i had the same issue with "Croppie" just like @arun-raj. After a lot of tests i found a very similar solution like @Rúbel.

In my proyects i use "reset.css" to achieve the same look cross browser.
But when i used "Croppie" it dont work properly. I realized that only 1 css rule caused that issue in "Croppie". In "reset.css" line 44 there is:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Just delete this rule, wether you use "reset.css" or not.

Try this examples:

[Croppie with "reset.css" with img rule](https://www.nubeduc.cl/croppie/index.html)

[Croppie without css img rule](https://www.nubeduc.cl/croppie/index2.html)

Just check the page source to see the code and "Croppie" working properly.
Hope this help you too!

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with version 2.5.0

Switching to the version prior to that -- 2.4.1 -- solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please attach the code?
It looks like you crop out the top left part of the image instead of the selected area.

EDIT:
It looks like you are creating the croppie with the size 175x175 from the viewport. Then you just save the resulting image of 175x175 even if it is larger. That is why you always get the 175x175 pixels of the top left corner. Have a closer look at the documentation: https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

Comment: Yes It is getting cropped like dat

Comment: Can you attach the whole function? We need some more code to find out what is wrong

Comment: I couldn't solve it and i reverted back to version 2.4.1 and now it works just fine

Comment: I have the same issue, I can't the solve it. Please, help me